# Problema com a camera do Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, script, unity-5, 2d

Estou criando um jogo com unity 5 em 2d, e tentava criar um script para a câmera seguir o personagem movimentando o transform da câmera.
Para isso segui alguns tutoriais do youtube mas quando fui compilar o código indicou no método Lerp, tentei ajustar o código de varias formas e não obtive solução, o que envio aqui e a ultima versão do código que já mudei infinitas vezes não dando em nada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá. Bem vindo ao SOPT. Antes de mais nada, fica uma dica pra outras perguntas no futuro: não poste imagens com screenshots do seu código. Poste o código em forma textual (devidamente formatado de forma automática pelo sistema)! Assim, qualquer pessoa interessada pode simplesmente copiar um trecho sem precisar digitar tudo manualmente.

Answer (score 4):

Como a mensagem de erro indica, a sua chamada do método [Lerp](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) espera parâmetros diferentes dos que você passou. Ela espera dois `Vector3` (`a` e `b`) e um `float` (`t`), porque o que esse método faz é interpolar entre dois vetores `a` e `b` em um intervalo `t`.

Vc está passando no primeiro parâmetro, por exemplo, `MCamera.position.x`, que é o componente `x` (um valor `float`) do vetor `position`. Você provavelmente deveria passar ai `MCamera.position` diretamente (e o mesmo vale para o parâmetro `transform.position.x`, que deveria ser só `transform.position`).

Se o seu interesse é interpolar apenas o valor de `x` mesmo, experiemente com `Vector3(transform.position.x, 0, 0)` (cria um novo vetor apenas com o seu valor `x`, e com o valor `0` para os componentes `y` e `z`).

> P.S.: Você também deveria fazer a última linha ser `MCamera.position =
>   vetor` ao invés de `MCamera.position.x = vetor`.

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa seria simplesmente arrastar a Câmara para *dentro* (child) do Personagem. Assim, sempre que o personagem se movimentar, a câmara vai atrás sem necessitar de escrever 1 única linha de código.

[image: Processo de hierarquização: passagem da câmara para objeto-filho da personagem]

Comment: Olá. É realmente uma ótima alternativa. Mas a sua resposta poderia ter algumas informações adicionais. Vc poderia, por exemplo, incluir imagens detalhando o processo de hierarquização da câmera como objeto-filho do personagem, pra facilitar para algum leitor inexperiente. Se fizer isso ganha o meu +1. :)